# How to make AppCompatSpinner more visible to the user?

Tags: android, material-design, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I'm using android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner. 
My problem is that the down arrow triangle shape is too small. There is no background default color set for the spinner either. Though the user can hardly know there is even a spinner on the page cause it pretty much looks like a simple text view.
The arrow size cannot be changed and become bigger.
When I try to put background the small arrow totally goes away! 
What am I supposed to do?
I found no related guide in material design documents.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is my material design spinner:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:entries="@array/contract_type_array"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                style="@style/StyleForSimpleSpinnerMedium"
                android:background="@color/Color5"
                />

    <style name="StyleForSimpleSpinnerMedium">
    <item name="android:padding">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@android:drawable/list_selector_background</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
</style>
```